# Incorrect JSON format when added UNION ALL in query JSON output SQL

Tags: json, sql-server

I cannot work it properly when I put UNION ALL to my query. Please don't mind the OPENQUERY as I need to connect to our HANA server as it does currently not support the JSON_QUERY with our current version. My expected output is like this

```
[
   {
      "DocEntry":5,
      "CardCode":"VIT00021-EUR",
      "DocDate":"2019-05-16T00:00:00",
      "CompanyID":"LEAPTRON",
      "Lines":[
         {
            "LineNum":0,
            "ItemCode":"SERVO-GEARHEADS-DPL84/2-SM34-16-9.53",
            "Quantity":2,
            "WhsCode":"WH1-C"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "DocEntry":6,
      "CardCode":"VIT00021-EUR",
      "DocDate":"2019-05-16T00:00:00",
      "CompanyID":"DIRAK",
      "Lines":[
         {
            "LineNum":0,
            "ItemCode":"TEST",
            "Quantity":5,
            "WhsCode":"WH1-C"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

But when added the UNION ALL, the Lines tag is removed.

```
[
   {
      "DocEntry":5,
      "CardCode":"VIT00021-EUR",
      "DocDate":"2019-05-16T00:00:00",
      "CompanyID":"LEAPTRON",
      "LineNum":0,
      "ItemCode":"SERVO-GEARHEADS-DPL84/2-SM34-16-9.53",
      "Quantity":2,
      "WhsCode":"WH1-C"
   },
   {
      "DocEntry":8,
      "CardCode":"VIT00025-EUR",
      "DocDate":"2017-07-03T00:00:00",
      "CompanyID":"DIRAK",
      "LineNum":5,
      "ItemCode":"359-9505.04-00000",
      "Quantity":150,
      "WhsCode":"DSO-C"
   }
]
```

This is my query with UNION ALL

```
SELECT Header.DocEntry, Header.CardCode, Header.DocDate, Header.CompanyID, Lines.LineNum, Lines.ItemCode, Lines.Quantity, Lines.WhsCode 
FROM OPENQUERY (HANAAPI, 'SELECT TOP 1 "DocEntry", "CardCode", "DocDate", ''LEAPTRON'' "CompanyID" FROM "LEAPTRON_LIVE"."OPDN"') Header 
INNER JOIN OPENQUERY (HANAAPI, 'SELECT "LineNum", "DocEntry", "ItemCode", "Quantity", "WhsCode" FROM "LEAPTRON_LIVE"."PDN1"') Lines ON Header."DocEntry" = Lines."DocEntry"
UNION ALL
SELECT Header.DocEntry, Header.CardCode, Header.DocDate, Header.CompanyID, Lines.LineNum, Lines.ItemCode, Lines.Quantity, Lines.WhsCode 
FROM OPENQUERY (HANAAPI, 'SELECT TOP 1 "DocEntry", "CardCode", "DocDate", ''DIRAK'' "CompanyID" FROM "DIRAK181025"."OPDN"') Header 
INNER JOIN OPENQUERY (HANAAPI, 'SELECT "LineNum", "DocEntry", "ItemCode", "Quantity", "WhsCode" FROM "DIRAK181025"."PDN1"') Lines ON Header."DocEntry" = Lines."DocEntry"
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `AUTO`, the design of the JSON is based on the tables and views present in the outermost part of the query.

So if your query is:

```sql
SELECT Header.DocEntry, Header.CardCode, Header.DocDate, Header.CompanyID, Lines.LineNum, Lines.ItemCode, Lines.Quantity, Lines.WhsCode 
FROM OPENQUERY (HANAAPI, 'SELECT TOP 1 "DocEntry", "CardCode", "DocDate", ''LEAPTRON'' "CompanyID" FROM "LEAPTRON_LIVE"."OPDN"') Header 
INNER JOIN OPENQUERY (HANAAPI, 'SELECT "LineNum", "DocEntry", "ItemCode", "Quantity", "WhsCode" FROM "LEAPTRON_LIVE"."PDN1"') Lines ON Header."DocEntry" = Lines."DocEntry"
```

then `Header` and `Lines` are visible in the outermost scope of the query.

Whereas, in the `UNION ALL` version, the two halves are unioned before `FOR JSON` sees it. It's basically the equivalent of:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT Header.DocEntry, Header.CardCode, Header.DocDate, Header.CompanyID, Lines.LineNum, Lines.ItemCode, Lines.Quantity, Lines.WhsCode 
    FROM OPENQUERY (HANAAPI, 'SELECT TOP 1 "DocEntry", "CardCode", "DocDate", ''LEAPTRON'' "CompanyID" FROM "LEAPTRON_LIVE"."OPDN"') Header 
    INNER JOIN OPENQUERY (HANAAPI, 'SELECT "LineNum", "DocEntry", "ItemCode", "Quantity", "WhsCode" FROM "LEAPTRON_LIVE"."PDN1"') Lines ON Header."DocEntry" = Lines."DocEntry"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Header.DocEntry, Header.CardCode, Header.DocDate, Header.CompanyID, Lines.LineNum, Lines.ItemCode, Lines.Quantity, Lines.WhsCode 
    FROM OPENQUERY (HANAAPI, 'SELECT TOP 1 "DocEntry", "CardCode", "DocDate", ''DIRAK'' "CompanyID" FROM "DIRAK181025"."OPDN"') Header 
    INNER JOIN OPENQUERY (HANAAPI, 'SELECT "LineNum", "DocEntry", "ItemCode", "Quantity", "WhsCode" FROM "DIRAK181025"."PDN1"') Lines ON Header."DocEntry" = Lines."DocEntry"
) AS UnnamedTable
FOR JSON AUTO
```

This cannot be fixed with `FOR JSON PATH` because `FOR JSON PATH` will not create arrays. `FOR JSON AUTO` will do so because it sees that the values are the same on subsequent rows.

Instead we can rebuild the structure on the outside

```sql
SELECT
    Header.DocEntry, Header.CardCode, Header.DocDate, Header.CompanyID,
    Lines.LineNum, Lines.ItemCode, Lines.Quantity, Lines.WhsCode

FROM (
    SELECT Header.DocEntry, Header.CardCode, Header.DocDate, Header.CompanyID, Lines.LineNum, Lines.ItemCode, Lines.Quantity, Lines.WhsCode 
    FROM OPENQUERY (HANAAPI, 'SELECT TOP 1 "DocEntry", "CardCode", "DocDate", ''LEAPTRON'' "CompanyID" FROM "LEAPTRON_LIVE"."OPDN"') Header 
    INNER JOIN OPENQUERY (HANAAPI, 'SELECT "LineNum", "DocEntry", "ItemCode", "Quantity", "WhsCode" FROM "LEAPTRON_LIVE"."PDN1"') Lines ON Header."DocEntry" = Lines."DocEntry"

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Header.DocEntry, Header.CardCode, Header.DocDate, Header.CompanyID, Lines.LineNum, Lines.ItemCode, Lines.Quantity, Lines.WhsCode 
    FROM OPENQUERY (HANAAPI, 'SELECT TOP 1 "DocEntry", "CardCode", "DocDate", ''DIRAK'' "CompanyID" FROM "DIRAK181025"."OPDN"') Header 
    INNER JOIN OPENQUERY (HANAAPI, 'SELECT "LineNum", "DocEntry", "ItemCode", "Quantity", "WhsCode" FROM "DIRAK181025"."PDN1"') Lines ON Header."DocEntry" = Lines."DocEntry"
) AS Header

CROSS APPLY (SELECT
    Lines.LineNum, Lines.ItemCode, Lines.Quantity, Lines.WhsCode
) ) Lines

FOR JSON AUTO
```

As you can see, this is pretty verbose. You may want to restructure the query so that the unions are inside of the join, which simplifies it back to what it was:

```sql
SELECT Header.DocEntry, Header.CardCode, Header.DocDate, Header.CompanyID, Lines.LineNum, Lines.ItemCode, Lines.Quantity, Lines.WhsCode

FROM (
    SELECT *
      FROM OPENQUERY (HANAAPI, 'SELECT TOP 1 "DocEntry", "CardCode", "DocDate", ''LEAPTRON'' "CompanyID" FROM "LEAPTRON_LIVE"."OPDN"') Header
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
      FROM OPENQUERY (HANAAPI, 'SELECT TOP 1 "DocEntry", "CardCode", "DocDate", ''DIRAK'' "CompanyID" FROM "DIRAK181025"."OPDN"') Header
) Header

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *
      FROM OPENQUERY (HANAAPI, 'SELECT "LineNum", "DocEntry", "ItemCode", "Quantity", "WhsCode" FROM "LEAPTRON_LIVE"."PDN1"') Lines
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
      FROM OPENQUERY (HANAAPI, 'SELECT "LineNum", "DocEntry", "ItemCode", "Quantity", "WhsCode" FROM "DIRAK181025"."PDN1"') Lines
) Lines
  ON Header."DocEntry" = Lines."DocEntry"

FOR JSON AUTO;
```

Comment: As I test your solution, the result is like this. [link](https://pastebin.com/zrfCRmQp).
The "DocEntry":17 has multiple lines. It should be in 1 array.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Here's the result based from the edit. [link](https://pastebin.com/z02RMyTb) but what I'm trying to do is like this [link](https://pastebin.com/X9ifLsm1) is it possible?

Comment: Hum I think you're right, it can't be done with `JSON PATH`, I've given you a couple more solutions